# ES6 module import export with webpack and babel-loader

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) with `babel-loader` to transpile my ES6/JSX, which gets split into server and client bundles:

```
//components/CustomerView.jsx
export default class CustomerView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}

//components/index.js
import CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
export {CustomerView}

//client.js
var Components = require('expose?Components!./components');

//webpack.config.js (loader section)
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
```

The above works, but based on the example in the `Syntax` section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), which mentions babel supports it, so i assumed i could write something like the following, but it doesnt work:

```
export CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
```

Also, it doesnt work if the class isnt the default export class:

```
export class CustomerView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors from webpack, it creates the bundles but when i run it i get `Could not find a component named 'Components.CustomerView'`, so for some reason unless it's the default export the `expose-loader` doesnt seeem to be creating the `Components` global, or not attaching `CustomerView` to it.. any ideas?

Comment: I blame babel's [tutorial](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) lol

Comment: @AmanuelBogale That is the official specification name, like it or not. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ "ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification" Both names are valid, and moving forward the year versions will be more common.

Comment: Dosent matter @loganfsmyth i dont like that name. Just say ES6 or ES7... Im tired of it

Comment: @NickDewitt You have two separate "doesn't work" examples, in the first, does it give you a syntax error, or silently fail like your second example?

Comment: Hmm i thought they were both failing, but `export CustomerView from ...` but `babel-loader` wouldn't compile that, but `export {CustomerView} from` actually works

Comment: @loganfsmyth i'm confused now i can't even reproduce it, i did have webpack running with `--watch` and have restarted it since.. how frustrating!

Comment: ah no, it seems you have to use the parentheses `{}` unless there is a default export declared..

Comment: @loganfsmyth managed to reproduce it, put my findings in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What i should have done:**

Wrap the export values in `{}`:

```
export {CustomerView} from './CustomerView.jsx'
```

**The reason i got confused:**

This only works when the `CustomerView`class is the default export:

```
import CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
```

When there is no default class export, it needs to be wrapped in curlies or it doesn't work:

```
import {CustomerView} from './CustomerView.jsx'
```

but for some reason, `babel-loader` wouldnt compile this when there was a default class export:

```
export CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
```

or this

```
import CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
export CustomerView
```

a combination of the 2 compiled, but gave me the `could not find a component` error (this is react.net pre-rendering) unless i set the default class export in `CustomerView.jsx`, which i guess meant it was chaining through to this import/export:

```
import CustomerView from './CustomerView.jsx'
export {CustomerView}
```